# UIFont exc_bad_access error in iOS 4.3

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel, exc-bad-access, ios4

I am setting the font property of a label using the `fontWithSize:` method and while it works fine in iOS 5, iOS 4.3 I am getting an exc_bad_access error. Here is my code:

```
UILabel *headerText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width - 10, 42)];

headerText.text = [tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];


headerText.font = [[UIFont alloc] fontWithSize:8];
```

Again, this code works perfectly in iOS 5, but crashes as the last line in 4.3. I checked the Apple API docs and `fontWithSize:` as well as the font property of a `UILabel` have both been around since iOS 2. Is there anything else wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use alloc to initial, the method usually begins with `init`.

`fontWithSize :` is not used to initial.

> Returns a font object that is the same as the receiver but which has the specified size instead.

It means that you should call it using an existing font instance.
For example:

```
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    UIFont *newFont = [font fontWithSize:24];
```

But if you want to initial an instance, you need call the class method or instance method beginning with init.

Comment: Using [UIFont fontWithSize:8] gets me the error that there is no such class method for UIFont and the docs classify it as an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why what I tried above works in iOS 5?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call methods on an object that was never initialized. Specifically, your line

```
[[UIFont alloc] fontWithSize:8]
```

is `alloc`ing a new font object, but then never initializing it. The subsequent call to `-fontWithSize:` is crashing because it assumes the object has been initialized.

What font were you trying to create? Since you skipped the initializer, you never provided a font family. Of course, UIFont doesn't even expose a good initializer (you could call `-init` but there's no way to provide the font family). This is an indication that you're supposed to use the class "convenience" methods to construct your font, e.g. `+[UIFont fontWithName:size]` or `+[UIFont systemFontOfSize:]`. In your case I'm assuming you want the latter, so you should use

```
[UIFont systemFontOfSize:8]
```

Comment: Kevin, thanks for your answer. Do you happen to know why the above works in iOS 5 though?

Comment: @AndrewBarinov: Because you're getting lucky. Calling any non-init method on an uninitialized object has undefined behavior. The fact that it works in iOS 5 and not earlier is just a consequence of calling undefined behavior (e.g. the result is undefined). It's likely that `-fontWithSize:` no longer makes the assumption that an ivar is non-nil (or alternately, a method/function it invokes no longer makes the assumption that input is non-nil).

Answer (score 0):

`fontWithSize` is a class method not an instance method

basically you dont allocate a UIFont object, you just call `[UIFont fontWithSize:8]`

Comment: oop my bad, i was thinking of systemFontOfSize: :P
ive never seen that method used

Comment: yeah that happens to me all the time too